# symfony email errors

Tags: symfony1

Here's an interesting question, that I'm pretty sure symfony can do.

we're launching a site in the next little while, and right now I have all symfony exceptions show up on the front page (well we're in dev :)).

is it possible for me to get symfony to email that information to me, every time somebody encounters it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe [this](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfErrorNotifierPlugin) plugin should do the job.